# Is iPhone supported for multi-tasking in iOS 9

Tags: ios, ios9

I opt in mutli-tasking for my Universal app. for the iPad it's so clear what's feature it gives. and how to test it on simulator.

The problem with the iPhone. Is it supported? What are the provided features? How to test it on simulator?

**Edit:**

What I mean exactly is the new things introduced for the first time in iOS 9. exactly the split screen, slide over and the picture in picture features.

Comment: If you're talking about the new split screen and slide over features, it's for Ipad Air 2 only at the moment. But multitasking features in general has been in iPhone for a while: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html You should probably make your question more clear.

Comment: I think that was pretty obvious

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iPhone and iPod touch users cannot use the multitasking features of iOS 9.

Multitasking is only available on:

- iPad Air
- iPad Air 2
- iPad mini 2
- iPad mini 3

Note: Split View is only available on the iPad Air 2

See for more information about multitasking: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/index.html

Comment: Ok, the one who down voted this. can you add an answer. demonstrating the features on iPhone?

Comment: Sure is: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to multitasking enhancements in iOS 9, they are available only on iPads.

A table is available on official Apple guide [Adopting Multitasking Enhancements on iPad](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/index.html).

[image]